# Help with error handling for Python

Tags: python, error-handling

For the simple snippet below

```
a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
```

How can I write an exception such that if a string is entered, the user is re-prompted to try again and again until an integer is entered.

In other words, keep doing this until an integer is entered.:

```
if a.isdigit == False:
    raw_input("Try again: ")
```

Comment: my answer is no use for you i will delete it, if you want just positive numbers choose one of the answer that use `isdigit()` , hope i did help this time :)

Comment: I think my question was poorly worded that confused everyone -_-. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is to use `int()` with exception handling:

```
>>> n = None
>>> while n is None:
...    a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
...    try:
...      n = int(a)
...    except ValueError:
...      print "Not a number."
...
Enter a number: abc
Not a number.
Enter a number: cauliflowers are my favourite vegetable
Not a number.
Enter a number: 12
>>>
```

However if you would prefer to avoid exception handling you can take the following approach.  Note that it does not accept negative integers, but only the natural numbers `0, 1, 2, ..., N`:

```
>>> while True:
...   a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
...   if a.isdigit():
...     break
...   print "Not a number."
...
Enter a number: I like beetroot too
Not a number.
Enter a number: -500
Not a number.
Enter a number: 500
>>>
```

It becomes a little more involved to handle negative integers in this manner, requiring three cases, one for empty strings, one for negative integers and one for natural numbers:

```
>>> while True:
...   a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
...   if len(a) > 0 and ((a[0] == '-' and a[1:].isdigit()) or a.isdigit()):
...     break
...   print "Not a number."
...
Enter a number: Celery stinks.
Not a number.
Enter a number:
Not a number.
Enter a number: -
Not a number.
Enter a number: 1
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to use `try...except`? If an addition `int(a) > 0` condition was added to the answers you downvoted, wont it make their solution valid as well?

Comment: @Nai In answer to your first question, the `try... except` is required because `int(a)` returns an integer, not a boolean, and uses exceptions to signal the case where it is dealing with a string that is not a valid integer.  This is why adding `int(a) > 0` to the `isdigit` answers is not enough, as `int` will throw an exception if confronted with a non-integer representing string.

Comment: @Nai Having said that, if you do only want to find natural numbers (`0, 1, 2, ..., N`) rather than integers (`-N, ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., N`) I would recommend updating your question and using Jeff or Michaels answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
a = ""
while not a.isdigit():
    a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
```

If you want an error message it becomes something like:

```
a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
while not a.isdigit():
    a = raw_input("Try again: ")
```

Comment: @fmark I think it's implied that he means natural numbers; he used `.isdigit` right in his question...

Comment: Sorry, I can't change my downvote now unless you edit your answer.

Comment: @fmark Don't worry about it, unless you badly want your 1 rep back (you can always edit the answer too; it doesn't need to be the poster)

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    try:
        i = int(a)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
while (not a.isdigit()):
    a = raw_input("Try again: ")
```